# Twitter API user categories - what is 'size'?

Tags: twitter

I would like to be able to categorise our users who log in with twitter by interest. For example, "Technology", "Sport", etc.

It looks like the twitter API for this is here:
https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/users/suggestions

I am not quite sure exactly what this is for, and the documentation does not say what the "size" in the response is.

For reference, the result is a JSON with lots of results in this format:

```
  {
    "name": "Art & Design",
    "slug": "art-design",
    "size": 20
  }
```

So my assumption is that this user is interested in "Art & Design", but what is the 20? Also, is this the correct purpose of the API?

(I notice my account says I am interested in several things which are correct, then it lists Strictly Come Dancing, which I am not too interested in).

For my account after I formatted the response as i'm using twitter4j and don't know how to see the raw result, the result looks like (after formatting where the first value is the name, the second is the size and the third is the slug):

```
News:32:news:
Entertainment:20:entertainment:
Television:42:television:
Government:26:government:
Music:39:music:
Sport:63:sport:
Actors & Actresses:12:actors-actresses:
Literature:27:literature:
London Fashion Week:17:london-fashion-week:
Comedians:12:comedians:
Technology:19:technology:
Business:43:business:
Fashion:26:fashion:
Art and Design:46:art-and-design:
Chefs:10:chefs:
Travel:39:travel:
London Services:54:london-services:
Science:30:science:
Charity and NGOs:29:charity-and-ngos:
Christmas Television:32:christmas-television:
Strictly Come Dancing:36:strictly-come-dancing:
#TweetsFromTheTop:32:tweetsfromthetop:
```

Note: I tested that running this multiple times returns the same results (That's a good start), and I can see on my account they are mostly relevant to me, but i'm still unsure about this 'size' variable.

There is no chance it is suggesting only 32 people are interested in News. Also, I do not have 63 followers yet, so there is no chance it's a count of followers interested in these categories. It is just some rough measure of how interested I am in those categories? If this was the case, i'd be interested to know what the min/max values are.

Thanks,

Comment: How interested he is?

Comment: Is that a measurement from 1 to 100? This number is useful to me if I can say, for example only use tags over 50, but I am unsure what the max is or how it is calculated. Perhaps a user who uses his twitter more would end up with 100, or more (depending on what it is), in lots of categories? Is there any documentation anywhere?